# Dots on Meteor Templates Names

Tags: templates, meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

So, I've been trying to create a Template called "Chart.Line" using Meteor's Spacebar syntax. So, if I do this:

```
<template name="Chart">
   // random stuff here
</template>
```

and later import it using {{> Chart}} anywhere I want, then all the random stuff runs as expected. But if I define the Template like this:

```
<template name="Chart.List">
   // random stuff here
</template>
```

then, nothing works.

My question is: what's wrong here? I've been looking on documentation and source code forever, but I can't figure out what's wrong with using dots on this particular situation.

P.S.: yes, calling it "Chart.List" instead of "Chart_List" or something similar would be extremelly desirable.

Comment: This will probably fail because whenever a bit of javascript wants to refer to that template, javascript will interpret the `.list` as a property of the `chart` object. I suspect there are places in Blaze where this is happening.

Comment: I did some digging with Chrome's debugging tool and found that a Spacebar.dot object is being created. I don't know if it's related to what you said.

Anyway, thanks for you help.

(edit for formatting and cleaning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dots in a template name.

Blaze will try and access the `List` property of `Chart` instead of the template called `Chart.List` (as was mentioned in the comments).